# Dropdown menu doesn't work

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver

i am making a website for my family run business and I an trying to get a dropdown menu to work properly. I am trying to get the 'plant list' item to link to the 'plant list intro' page and then I would like it to drop down and show the the other pages that I want it to link to.

I managed to get it working before using an extension but even when I edit the template on the extension it messes up my design of the webpage.

Here is a code from one of my pages I am working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hocklynn Index</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Ralph Phillips">
    <script src="../css/stylesheet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("../css/stylesheet.css");
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="../images/Hocklynn Logo/Hocklynn-Logo-High-Rez.png" width="351" height="91" alt="" class="header-logo" />
        <div class="header-meta">
            <p>Tel: 0117 951 7572</p>
            <p>Fax: 0117 951 601</p>
            <p>Email: info@hocklynn.co.uk</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC">
   <!-- AJXFILE:../css/stylesheet.css -->
     <ul class="wrapper">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="ajxsub" href="Plant List Intro.html">Plant&nbsp;List</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Plant%20List%20Laser.html">Laser</a></li>
            <li><a href="Plant%20List%20Press%20Brake.html">Press Brake</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Welding</a></li>
            <li><a href="Plant%20List%20-%20Other.html">Other Plant</a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="CAD%20Facilities.html">CAD&nbsp;Facilities</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="../images/Sheet Metal Fabrication.jpg" class="max-width" />
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
  @charset "utf-8";
/*
 Ajatix Advanced CSS Drop Down Menu Light
 Copyright (C) 2009-2014 Ajatix. All rights reserved.
 http://www.ajatix.com
*/

body {
    font-family: "Verdana", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header-logo {
    float: left;
}

.header-meta {
    float: right;
    color: #2D3C73;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:300px;
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.content img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    padding:5px;
}

.max-width {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC {position:relative;z-index:100;line-height:0;background:#2e6fa9 url(stylesheet_files/menu-bg.gif) top right;text-align:center;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC ul {position:relative;display:inline-block;margin:0;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;list-style-type:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;}
*+html .AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC ul {display:inline;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li {float:left;margin:0; padding: 0 40px;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li:hover,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li.ajxover {position:relative;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC a,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC_n a {display:block;overflow:hidden;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li>a {width:auto;height:41px;white-space:nowrap;padding:0 12px 0 12px;font:bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:41px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;text-align:center;border:0;color:#cae3f8;background:url(stylesheet_files/top.gif) top right;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li:hover>a,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li.ajxover>a {color:#ffffff;background:#5597d1 url(stylesheet_files/top.gif) bottom right;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li>a.ajxsub {padding:0 26px 0 12px;background:url(stylesheet_files/top-sub.gif) top right;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li:hover>a.ajxsub,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC>ul>li.ajxover>a.ajxsub {position: static;background:#5597d1 url(stylesheet_files/top-sub.gif) bottom right;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li ul {position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;width:200px;height:auto;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;font-size:0;float:none;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;border:1px solid #ffffff;background:#5597d1;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li:hover > ul,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li.ajxover > ul {left:-1px;top:41px;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li li {width:200px;margin:0;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li li a {width:176px;height:auto;white-space:normal;padding:9px 12px 9px 12px;font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:12px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;text-align:left;border:0;color:#ffffff;background:none;}
.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li li:hover>a,.AJXCSSMenufBJaaQC li li.ajxover>a {background:#2d6fa9;}
.wrapper {
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we7zhs19/) with my code.

Comment: Problem is in CSS, please add it. And `<script src="../css/stylesheet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is strange.

Comment: I have added my CSS code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with panthers comment. 
I guess the most common way to establish a dropdown-menu as shown in the html-markup you provide is hiding the sub-menu-list by css, which could look somewhat like this:

```
.ajxsub ul { display: none; }
```

In the corresponding .js-file there might be some toggle like

```
$(".ajxsub").click(function () {
    $( ".ajxsub ul" ).toggle();
});
```

Please note that i use jQuery here. You need to implement jQuery in your html file ;)

Plus: I just have written this down quickly without testing it (due to a lack of time...) this is just one way in which direction your problem can be solved and there are a lot more.

Comment: My css works well even without the path there but I'm trying to get the drop down to work. I would like the plant list page to go to the intro page and then the user would click on the drop down and they will be able to access to the pages that are there. I was using some Adobe extension to create the nav bar and then I edited it to how I wanted my page to look and now the drop-down part doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give script src as src="../css/stylesheet.js" and in import url "../"

Give exact path name where file located i,e   src="http://projectfolder/yourcssfolder/filename.js"